# Template struct to hold two types but only one at the time

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to implement a template structure that lets me hold two data types (event not compatible with each other) on the same data structure. I know there is boost::any that already does something similar to what I want to achieve, but I can't add boost to my project.

A snipped of what I got so far is inside the following code that works on MSVC, but won't even compile on Xcode with Clang, telling me `Cannot specialize a function 'Get' within class scope` on every specialization of the `Get` method of my structure.

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible (boost does it so I think it is)? How can I fix my code to make it work?

```
template<typename TypeA, typename TypeB>
struct Either
{
public:
    // ...
    // CODE NOT USEFUL TO THE QUESTION HERE
    // ...

    /** Returns true when the value is meaningful; false if calling GetValueA() or GetValueB() is undefined. */
    bool IsSet() const { return _typeASet || _typeBSet; }
    inline explicit operator bool() const { return _typeASet || _typeBSet; }

    /** Returns true when the value is meaningful; false if calling GetValueA() is undefined. */
    bool IsASet() const { return _typeASet; }

    /** Returns true when the value is meaningful; false if calling GetValueB() is undefined. */
    bool IsBSet() const { return _typeBSet; }

    /** Fallback for wrong type */
    template<typename T>
    const T& Get() const
    {
        static_assert(false, "Cannot get a value which is neither TypeA nor TypeB");
    }

    /** Fallback for wrong type */
    template<typename T>
    T& Get()
    {
        static_assert(false, "Cannot get a value which is neither TypeA nor TypeB");
    }

    /** Specialize to get TypeA */
    template<>
    const TypeA& Get() const
    {
        if(!IsASet())
            throw "Invalid operation";
        return *(TypeA*)&_valueA;
    }

    /** Specialize to get TypeA */
    template<>
    TypeA& Get()
    {
        if(!IsASet())
            throw "Invalid operation";
        return *(TypeA*)&_valueA;
    }

    /** Specialize to get TypeB */
    template<>
    const TypeB& Get() const
    {
        if(!IsBSet())
            throw "Invalid operation";
        return *(TypeB*)&_valueB;
    }

    /** Specialize to get TypeB */
    template<>
    TypeB& Get()
    {
        if(!IsBSet())
            throw "Invalid operation";
        return *(TypeB*)&_valueB;
    }

private:
    /** Indicates that the TypeA values is the one being */
    bool _typeASet;

    /** Indicates that the TypeB values is the one being */
    bool _typeBSet;

    /** Placeholder for TypeA value */
    TypeCompatibleBytes<TypeA> _valueA;

    /** Placeholder for TypeB value */
    TypeCompatibleBytes<TypeB> _valueB;
};
```

I'd like to keep the following syntax working:

```
Either<int, float> value(5);                    // Holds the int value

int intVal = value.Get<int>();                  // Works returning 5
float fltVal = value.Get<float>();              // Compiles but throws exeption (the in value is the valid one)
std::string strVal = value.Get<std::string>();  // Doesn't compile due to static_assert inside Get
```

Comment: I could think of some `union` declaration inside the template struct  and keep an indicator wich of the types was used for initialization.

Comment: Your compiler error is because you need to move those template specializations out of the class. As @πάνταῥεῖ says, a `union` is probably a good choice for the underlying storage.

Comment: Actually I store the data for the two types on that `TypeCompatibleBytes` which allocates enough memory to hold each data type (although if you show me an alternative I can switch to that). BTW, how can I specialize those functions outside the class? I would still need to know about both `TypeA` and `TypeB` right?

Comment: `union` is always evil if you ask me, it only happens sometimes to be the lesser one, like most of C legacy.

Comment: C++ 17 has [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't rely on C++17 because not all compilers support it as of now (can't ask to the company to switch to VS2015 or VS2017)

Comment: The error is simply because you cannot do an explicit specialization within a class declaration, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template . That said, I thought about how to do what you want, mostly as an exercise since I see no application that really needs this, but I failed. Using an union did not work out for me, except if you do something like get_type_A(){return union_content.a;}, which you probably don't want. Very good question.

Comment: Although one can do this if every possibility for A and B is known, union Content{Type1 type_1; Type2  type_2;...} outside of the class and then explicitely specializing each possibility outside of the declaration, that is Either<Type1,Type2>::Get<Type1>, Either... etc - if you got enough possibilities, the only approach that does not waste LoC with endless repetitions might be by using macros to generate them, quite ugly. I think I will read in how std::variant does that.

Comment: @zeb so, did you take a look at how boost did it? It is open source. By the way, `boost::variant` is closer than `boost::any` to what you're attempting.

Comment: Two common ways to do this are recursive unions or `std::aligned_storage`.

Comment: @user2079303 you're right, `boost::variant` is closer than `boost::any`, my mistake. BTW, I took a look at `std::variant` and its a bit different (it also relies on an external `get` function, which I'm trying to avoid. I'll take a look at `boost::variant` now

Comment: @TartanLlama the storage isn't a problem, I'm already storing the values inside something like `std::aligned_storage`: My problem now is `Get` function which is a pain to specialize it seems

Comment: @user2079303 looks like `boost::variant` uses an external `get` function unfortunately

Comment: @zeb free `get` function  is superior to member, because member would require you to type `either.template Get<A>()` every time when `either` is a dependent name.

Comment: @yurikilochek what do you mean by dependent name?

Comment: @zeb as described in [temp.dep](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep), for example in `template <typename A, typename B> void printA(Either<A, B> const& e) { std::cout << e.template Get<A>(); }`  `Get` is a dependent (on template parameters) name, so it could be anything. `template` keyword is required to disambiguate it from expression with two comparison operators, i.e.  `e.Get < A > ()`.

Comment: @yurikilochek I see what you mean. Well, I guess I can expose both the member and the function to get the best of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot put specializations for member templates at class scope; they need to be at namespace scope. Unfortunately, you can't just move those specializations outside the class, because specializations of member templates need to also specialize the containing class template. A workaround is to do tag dispatching instead:

```
template <typename T> struct type{};

const TypeA& Get(type<TypeA>) const
{
    if(!IsASet())
        throw "Invalid operation";
    return *(TypeA*)&_valueA;
}

TypeA& Get(type<TypeA>)
{
    if(!IsASet())
        throw "Invalid operation";
    return *(TypeA*)&_valueA;
}

const TypeB& Get(type<TypeB>) const
{
    if(!IsBSet())
        throw "Invalid operation";
    return *(TypeB*)&_valueB;
}

TypeB& Get(type<TypeB>)
{
    if(!IsBSet())
        throw "Invalid operation";
    return *(TypeB*)&_valueB;
}

template<typename T>
T& Get()
{
    return Get(type<T>{});
}

template<typename T>
const T& Get() const
{
    return Get(type<T>{});
}
```

This provides separate overloads instead of specializations, then selects from the overloads by passing a tag as an argument. Note that I didn't try to compile this code, but it should give you the jist.

Comment: Works perfectly, just like @Aconcagua solution. I like this one a little bit more because it's simpler (personal thought) and easier to understand (again, personal thought)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename A, typename B>
struct Get; // leave unimplemented!

template <typename TypeA, typename TypeB>
struct Either
{
    enum State
    {
        E,
        A,
        B,
    } state;

    unsigned char data[sizeof(TypeA) > sizeof(TypeB) ? sizeof(TypeA) : sizeof(TypeB)];

    template <typename T, typename A, typename B>
    friend struct Get;

public:
    inline explicit operator bool() const { return isSet(); }
    bool isSet() const { return state != E; }
    bool isASet() const { return state == A; }
    bool isBSet() const { return state == B; }

    template<typename T>
    T& get() const
    {
        return Get<T, TypeA, TypeB>::get(this);
    }

    Either& operator=(TypeA const& a)
    {
        if(isBSet())
        {
            ((TypeB*)data)->~TypeB();
        }
        if(isASet())
        {
            *(TypeA*)data = a;
        }
        else
        {
            new (data)TypeA(a);
            state = A;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Either& operator=(TypeB const& b)
    {
        if(isASet())
        {
            ((TypeA*)data)->~TypeA();
        }
        if(isBSet())
        {
            *(TypeB*)data = b;
        }
        else
        {
            new (data)TypeB(b);
            state = B;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Get<A, A, B>
{
    static A& get(Either<A, B> const* e)
    {
        if(e->isASet())
        {
            return *(A*)e->data;
        }
        throw "Invalid operation";
    }
};
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Get<B, A, B>
{
    static B& get(Either<A, B> const* e)
    {
        if(e->isBSet())
        {
            return *(B*)e->data;
        }
        throw "Invalid operation";
    }
};
```

I avoided unions containing non-POD data types, instead I used a simple unsigned char array to hold the data, copying in the data via placement constructor.

Another problem to cope with was the fact that explicit template specialisations are required to reside at namespace scope. Well, fine, lets move them then at namespace scope - creating a template class providing the appropriate getters in two specialisations and call this one from the inner template function. As for the bad data types, there is no specialisation available, compilation will then fail appropriately.

Current implementation relies on copy constructor and assignment operator being available for both types, though...

```cpp
int main (void)
{
    Either<std::string, std::vector<int> > e;
    e = "hello";
    std::cout << e.get<std::string>() << std::endl;
    e = std::vector<int>();
    e.get<std::vector<int> >().push_back(10);
    std::cout << e.get<std::vector<int> >().back() << std::endl;

    Either<int, double > ee;
    ee = 12;
    std::cout << ee.get<int>() << std::endl;
    ee = 7.0;
    std::cout << ee.get<double>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Well, this test at least was successful...

Comment: Cool solution, you'll likely get alignment issues with using a bare character array for storage though.

Comment: @TartanLlama Thought about that, too... But shouldn't be the size of the outer class itself (which is then equal to the size of the larger of the two contained classes) be relevant for the alignment and thus fit???

Comment: If not, std::aligned_storage should solve the problem... C++17 is not desired, but C++11 shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution works perfectly. Although I would use my implemetation of a std::aligned_storage-like class for the storage.

Comment: FYI, I've chosen @TartanLlama solution only because I thinks it's simpler and more readable. This solution is perfectly acceptable (can't mark both as accepted answers sadly)